# Why does ` work for a code snippet, but ' doesn't?

Tags: support, markdown

I have a Cherry Stream XT Corded keyboard (http://www.cherrycorp.com/english/keyboards/Office/G85-23100/index.htm) with the Azerty(Belgium-point) keyboard layout.

When I use my <kbd>'</kbd> key on my keyboard to indicate the start and end of a code snippet 'like this', it does not register as a code snippet. I need to use <kbd>`</kbd>, which is an alt gr key on my keyboard. This makes entering code in a comment far trickier, especially when I didn't know about the alt gr key yet and manually copy-pasted the symbol from the help tooltip...

Is there a specific reason why this key is used as the in-line code key, instead of the other key I mentioned?

Comment: You can select the text you want to mark up as code and hit the `{}` button in the toolbar.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not when writing a comment.

Comment: No, not for comments. Markdown was envisioned as a plain-text-with-markup format, which is why *commonly used textual characters* are not used for markup. `'` is used extremely often in plain text, so it's not a candidate for code markup.

Comment: So your keyboard looks like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/93/Belgian_keyboard_layout.png)? (Where the characters marked red are green on yours.) About the only positive thing I can say about that layout (I'm Dutch but have *exclusively* used the US layout for 3 decades) is: hey, it has a `µ` key!

Comment: @Jongware Funnily enough, that's the only key that I never press on purpose (but often accidentally while pressing enter).µ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **<kbd>`</kbd>** was used as it\'s a character that isn\'t normally used in text.
**<kbd>'</kbd>** is, obviously.

Imagine the hassle of having to escape every single quote when you\'re writing an answer.

If anything, we should use **<kbd>.</kbd>**. I mean, who uses punctuation nowadays?

<sub>(Escapes are intentional)</sub>

Comment: "Isn\'t normally used in text..." - the second half is that it's still a key on *most* keyboards. It would not make much sense to use *any* random rare character such as `‡`.

Answer (score 5):

Single quotes, also known as apostrophes, are common punctuation marks in English and a common symbol used in most languages to represent chars or strings. Grave accents, not so much.

Granted you could use a fancy single quote to represent an apostrophe but there is no key on a standard keyboard for that character. If Markdown used single quotes for code formatting, it would be *extremely* difficult to type anything that requires an apostrophe.